# How to modify the size of the Accesory View in NSAlert?

Tags: swift, cocoa, alert, accessory, nsalert

Is it possible to modify the size of the accessory view on a NSAlert for Cocoa?

Let's say, in the image, INFORMATIVE TEXT is present, but if you remove it, is it possible to use that empty area in order to make the accessory view bigger (cyan area) so the accessory view can be closer to the title?

Thanks in advance.

[image: NSAlert]

Without the Informative Text, it looks like this:

[image: Alert 2]

What I want is the alert to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the informative text?

Comment: Yes, but the area is still there. The size of the accessory view doesn't increase.

Comment: Is the very long and detailed information one string without attributes?

Comment: No, it's a custom view that will be added to the alert, like this: alert.accessoryView = customView